# Logs are not loading using log4j2.properties file

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a problem with my log4j2.properties file, it works locally but not in remote.

```
rootLogger.level=all

rootLogger.appenderRefs=tlogpsc
rootLogger.appenderRef.tlogpsc.ref=tlogpsc

loggers=tlogpsc
logger.tlogpsc.name=tlogpsc
logger.tlogpsc.level=info
logger.tlogpsc.additivity = false
logger.tlogpsc.appenderRef.tlogpsc.ref=tlogpsc


appenders=tlogpsc
appender.tlogpsc.type=RollingFile
appender.tlogpsc.name=tlogpsc
appender.tlogpsc.fileName=logs/TLOGPSC/tlogpsc
appender.tlogpsc.filePattern=logs/TLOGPSC/tlogpsc.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.tlogpsc.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.tlogpsc.layout.pattern=%m%n
appender.tlogpsc.policies.type=Policies
appender.tlogpsc.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.tlogpsc.policies.time.interval=1
appender.tlogpsc.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.tlogpsc.policies.size.size=1MB
```

I want to log in `logs/app/app` in a remote (VM).